# Get the Name of connected device with Hotspot

Tags: android, file, sockets, share

How to get the name of device which connect from hotspot(server)?

One hotspot connect many device but nothing to get name of connected device, How to get it?

I can easy to get IP Address but how to get name?

Answer (score 1):

The below method will work but, this is detecting the version 4.0 and above; it is not able to find the devices with version 2.2 or 2.3 which is connected with hotspot.

```
public void getClientList() {
int macCount = 0;
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
        if (splitted != null ) {
            // Basic sanity check
            String mac = splitted[3];
            System.out.println("Mac : Outside If "+ mac );
            if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                macCount++;
               /* ClientList.add("Client(" + macCount + ")");
                IpAddr.add(splitted[0]);
                HWAddr.add(splitted[3]);
                Device.add(splitted[5]);*/
                System.out.println("Mac : "+ mac + " IP Address : "+splitted[0] );
                System.out.println("Mac_Count  " + macCount + " MAC_ADDRESS  "+ mac);
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Mac_Count  " + macCount + "   MAC_ADDRESS  "
                            + mac, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
           /* for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++)
                System.out.println("Addressssssss     "+ splitted[i]);*/

        }
    }
} catch(Exception e) {

}               
}
```

==>Check here :

Check [requestPeers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#requestPeers%28android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener%29) of [WifiP2pManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#requestPeers%28android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener%29)

As per documents it seeks [PeerListListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener.html) which returns [WifiP2pDeviceList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pDeviceList.html) carrying list of WifiP2pDevice which carries deviceAddress, deviceName, primaryDeviceType, secondaryDeviceType, status and other attributes.

Comment: this will only give host name or IP address only.

Comment: @jaimin, can don't get the name of device?

Comment: @ShubhamMaheshwari Edited the answer pls. check at bottom side.